# Installing and Accessing phpMyAdmin on a domain name

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a domain name hosted by Network Solution. I am developing a website using a version of phpMyAdmin which is more recent than the one running by NS and they are not willing to upgrade it for me. I saw a few post of people suggesting to install phpMyAdmin in my webspace which I didn't know was feasible.

I followed the steps and now have phpMyAdmin installed in www.banana.com/phpMyAdmin (where 'banana' is just an example).

Now, I have never configured something that different and complex before so really I have no clue what I am doing. I created a server using the the helper page .../phpMyAdmin/setup and moved the resulting config.inc.php file in the phpMyAdmin as explained in the doc. This is the content of my file:

```
/* Server: banana [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'banana';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'www.banana.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Aver1SecurEPasw0rd!';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
```

Now when I go the main page and asked to login, I use 'root' for the username and 'Aver1SecurEPasw0rd!' for the password, but I get a #2002 Cannot connect to MySQL server message. Since I am not sure what I am doing:

1. I am not sure actually running phpMyAdmin from my NS hosted domain name is possible?
2. What information I need to setup in the config file to actually login?

I spent a long time on the web to find some information about this, there seems to be no step by step guide for that sort of situation. If someone has done it or can help it would be fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more search and trials/errors I understand now how this works.

NS provides you with a list of database your created (in the cPanel). Now, in this list (in the MySQL database section) you will see a server name, a user name and password. This is the information you need to put in the 'config.inc.php' file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysqlvXXX'; /* this is the NS server on which is the DB is */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'NS_username'; /* your NS user name for that DB */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NS_password'; /* your NS password for that DB */
```

And this works. Well, now I need to update the version of php but that's another issue.